# Error starting up a backup WiredTiger mongodb Database

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I'm tasked to restore a WiredTiger mongodb backup on a new server, I've downloaded the folder to a path `/data/db`

But when
running `sudo mongod --dbpath=/data/db` on a new server, gave the following error.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.443+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.443+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.443+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":19032,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"ip-172-31-4-37"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.443+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.443+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.443+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/data/db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.444+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.444+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=94061M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.908+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604700676:908863][19032:0x7fd255377c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 4"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:16.953+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604700676:953627][19032:0x7fd255377c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 4"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:17.039+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604700677:39694][19032:0x7fd255377c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 3/640 to 4/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:17.040+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604700677:40016][19032:0x7fd255377c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 4"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:17.092+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604700677:92204][19032:0x7fd255377c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 4"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:17.134+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604700677:134313][19032:0x7fd255377c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (1604638812, 8737)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:17.134+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604700677:134351][19032:0x7fd255377c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (1604638812, 8737)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:25.589+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":9145}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:25.590+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":1604638812,"i":8737}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:25.591+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22383,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"The size storer reports that the oplog contains","attr":{"numRecords":327031365,"dataSize":133132846247}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:25.592+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22386,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Sampling the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:25.592+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22389,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Sampling from the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation","attr":{"from":{"$timestamp":{"t":1604570183,"i":3649}},"to":{"$timestamp":{"t":1604638812,"i":10667}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:25.592+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22390,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Taking samples and assuming each oplog section contains","attr":{"numSamples":991,"containsNumRecords":3296963,"containsNumBytes":1342177280}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.142+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22393,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Oplog sampling complete"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.142+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22382,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger record store oplog processing finished","attr":{"durationMillis":1550}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.176+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.177+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.177+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.177+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.187+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22167,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"You are running on a NUMA machine. We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems: numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.187+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22184,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Soft rlimits too low","attr":{"currentValue":1024,"recommendedMinimum":64000},"tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.189+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":21005,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Not restarting unfinished index builds because we are in standalone mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20573,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Wrong mongod version","attr":{"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: BadValue: Invalid value for version, found 4.0, expected '4.4' or '4.2'. Contents of featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"4.0\" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 4.2, see the documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#upgrade-procedures."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.284+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784934, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToDecreaseSnapshotHistoryCachePressure"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784916, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Reacquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784917, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to mark clean shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22372,   "ctx":"OplogVisibilityThread","msg":"Oplog visibility thread shutting down."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.285+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.286+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.286+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.286+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:27.286+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:28.544+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":1258}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:28.544+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:28.544+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:28.544+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-06T22:11:28.544+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":62}}
```

running `mongod` also gives the error above.

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at `"s": "F"` which is severity Fail.

After reading about [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/index.html#options-for-all-index-types) it seems the cause may have to do with index builds.

As it is advice in the log, upgrade your `mongod` from 4.0 to 4.4. See this document for [how to do upgrade](http://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#upgrade-procedures).

Comment: I am currently running 4.4 and this issue still persists

Comment: @mongotigerhelp .so the previous version was 4.0. So you should rollback, and do then upgrade using the link.